# Why does one misbehaving 32-bit process on a multicore 64-bit system freeze up all the 32-bit processes?

Tags: 64-bit

My laptop has Windows 7 x64 running on a triple-core AMD Phenom. Every time I have a 32-bit process go crazy and use 33% CPU (i.e., 100% on one core), every single other 32-bit process becomes unresponsive, while the 64-bit processes all hum along just fine, presumably on the other two cores. The only explanation I can think of for this is that WoW64 runs all 32-bit apps on a single core. Is that the case, or is it something else? And if so, is there any way to make it split them up like a good little multicore system should?

Thanks!

Comment: Educated guess, but only an educated guess: while the individual apps obviously run in their own threads, probably WoW64 itself isn't quite as isolated, so bad activity in one process can cause havoc to anything down the chain.

Comment: Is it one particular 32bit process "going crazy"? Or will any 32bit process cause this?

Comment: @Moab: It doesn't matter which one spikes (although it's usually Firefox).

Answer (score 1):

For clarity, the primary difference between 32-bit and 64-bit affects addressable RAM, and should not be related to multi processing.

Applications need to be developed and compiled to support multithreading properly. It is likely that the 32-bit applications you are seeing the issues with do not multithread very well, or depend on a process that does not multithread very well.

Comment: That is true as far as architecture goes, but Windows x64 does run 32-bit programs under some sort of emulation mode. So I'm not sure if this is the answer (though it does sound plausible).

Comment: sidran - yes, that is correct. Most 64-bit OSes can run both 32-bit and 64-bit applications. But this is unrelated to multi-threading, as I said.

Comment: Though I would have thought that even if an application is single-threaded, the OS would be smart enough to schedule it onto a free core. This is why I commented. The nature of how Windows schedules 32-bit emulated code may be different than how Windows schedules native 64-bit code.

Comment: Right, that's what I was asking: does WoW64 segregate all 32-bit code running on the system to a single core? I know "bitness" doesn't have to do with multithreading, but the fact that one swamped process takes down all the other 32-bit processes is very suspect.

Comment: Most applications in the 32-bit era were written in single-threaded environments, and never thought / cared to modify & recompile for multi-threading. What you are likely seeing is 32-bit applications that are still single-threaded. Firefox in particular - even the latest version 10 - is still single-threaded under a variety of circumstances (Javascript processing, plugins including Flash, etc.)

Comment: @Josh - I think Jarett understands that, but the trouble is that this explanation still doesn't really explain why ONE thread hanging will cause trouble in OTHER, completely unrelated, threads.  The only common link, if I'm understanding the complaint correctly, is that they're all 32-bit processes.